# Wrong images loaded after scrolling in collectionView swift 3

Tags: swift, image, scroll, uicollectionview

I am having issues with my collectionView in Swift 3. I have found some tips on Stackoverflow, tried them out, but alas to no avail. Many mentioned to use the 'prepareReuse' method, but I could not get those to work in my code. After Scrolling down, and back up again, the images have changed. All the images are letters of the alphabet. So A,B,C are the first images to appear at the top of the view. If you scroll down, and back up, some random other letters have taken their place. My entire code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class colViewController2: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var imageData: [String] = [String]()
var imageCounter: Int = 0
var userHasHieroglyph: NSArray = ["","","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageData = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    for b in imageData {
        if userHasHieroglyph.contains(b) {
            let newHieroglyph = b.lowercased()
            imageData[imageData.index(of: b)!] = "h-"+newHieroglyph
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! MyImageCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    var currImage:String = ""
    currImage = self.imageData[self.imageCounter]
    self.imageCounter += 1

    if self.imageCounter >= self.imageData.count {
        self.imageCounter = 0
    }

    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: currImage)
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 26
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
}
}
```

I hope I am missing some small bit of code to solve this problem, but after many hours of searching on Stackoverflow, and the internet, I still can not find a solution to this problem. If anyone has a solution or tip, it would be greatly appreciated!

Greetings

Comment: a note: in `numberOfItemsInSection` you should `return self.imageData.count`

Comment: a note: why you use `userHasHieroglyph: NSArray` and not just `[String]`

Comment: a note: since it is always white (in your code) you can put `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` in the init of MyImageCell

Comment: also with `var userHasHieroglyph: [String] = ` you can shorten your `imageData` init to this one line: `imageData = imageData.map{ userHasHieroglyph.contains($0) ? "h-"+$0.lowercased() : $0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using imageCounter as the index into your array of images, but incrementing it instead of using the `indexPath.item`. Remember that the UICollectionView will reuse UICollectionViewCell instances.  Basically, it will only create cell instances for those that are on the screen.  If a cell scrolls off the screen and a new one takes its place (e.g. if you have "A", "B", and "C" on the screen, and scroll down so you see "B", "C", "D", the UICollectionView will reuse the "A" cell for "D".  This is a bit of an oversimplification, but more or less how it works).  As such, the `cellForItem` call will give you the information about which cell is being displayed in the `indexPath` parameter.  In this case, you can get rid of all of the `self.imageCounter` logic and instead do `cell.image.image = UIImage(named: imageData[indexPath.row])`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! MyImageCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: imageData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! It is working now! Is this done to keep processing time at a minimum or is there another reason that you know of, why it behaves like this in the first place?

But as said, thank you very much!

Comment: I believe it's to reduce the number of object creations.  Likely for both time and memory consumption.  There's no reason to create a UICollectionViewCell (or UITableViewCell) for every element in the data array since likely only a few will ever be visible at once.  Also, if you're happy with this answer, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks.